# Installing snapd:arm64 showed these errors on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: 18.04, snap, raspberrypi, arm64

This printed when I installed 64-bit `snapd` on my Pi 3:

```
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic/main arm64 liblzo2-2 arm64 2.08-1.2 [42.2 kB]
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-updates/main arm64 apparmor arm64 2.12-4ubuntu5.1 [463 kB]
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic/main arm64 libfuse2 arm64 2.9.7-1ubuntu1 [68.4 kB]
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-updates/main arm64 squashfs-tools arm64 1:4.3-6ubuntu0.18.04.1 [96.9 kB]
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-updates/main arm64 snapd arm64 2.37.1+18.04 [12.9 MB]
Fetched 13.6 MB in 4s (3,673 kB/s)      
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 219459 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntu-core-launcher (2.34.2+18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblzo2-2:arm64.
(Reading database ... 219458 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../liblzo2-2_2.08-1.2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking liblzo2-2:arm64 (2.08-1.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apparmor:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../apparmor_2.12-4ubuntu5.1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking apparmor:arm64 (2.12-4ubuntu5.1) over (2.12-4ubuntu5.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfuse2:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../libfuse2_2.9.7-1ubuntu1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libfuse2:arm64 (2.9.7-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package squashfs-tools:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../squashfs-tools_1%3a4.3-6ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking squashfs-tools:arm64 (1:4.3-6ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (1:4.3-6ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package snapd:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.37.1+18.04_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd:arm64 (2.37.1+18.04) over (2.34.2+18.04) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libfuse2:arm64 (2.9.7-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up apparmor:arm64 (2.12-4ubuntu5.1) ...
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.11) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up liblzo2-2:arm64 (2.08-1.2) ...
Setting up squashfs-tools:arm64 (1:4.3-6ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up snapd:arm64 (2.37.1+18.04) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real ...
snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

Any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Try with an armhf version of snapd as raspberrypi 2,3 are armhf compatible, try and report any problems